# Firebase Crashlytics without Google Play Services

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Does Firebase Crashlytics works even without Google Play Services (GPS)? If so, what's the difference between devices that has GPS and has not in terms of reporting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase Crashlytics doesn't require Google Play Services to provide information you are used to seeing in the dashboard. This differs from some other Firebase services so our official policy is to state Firebase as a whole requires Play, but several services work without it.

Comment: Any idea how to remove the error printed out 5x during start up ? ```E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission```

Comment: @Todd is this still valid?

Comment: @JensMoser Yes. You can check from https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services